Google Form to Google Sheet, assigning a increment number based on dropdown selection
I have a Google Form that submits responses to a Google Sheet. I want to add an incremental number to every submitted row in Column D, and I want this number to be based on the maximum number already present in Column D. In other words, I want each new submission to receive the next available number after the highest number in Column A. How can I achieve this using Google Apps Script? The thing is that column D has several drop down options, so I want it to know its okay for Swimmers and lifeguards to both have the same number because although they are in the same column they are different dropdown answers. So we know that 4 Swimmers have replied and 2 Lifeguards have replied.
Here is the code that I've written so far

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var incrementCol = sheet.getLastColumn() + 1;
  // Add a header for the incremental number column if not already present 
  if (lastRow == 1 && !sheet.getRange(1, incrementCol).getValue()) {
    sheet.getRange(1, incrementCol).setValue("Incremental Number");
  }
    // Get the last incremental number 
    var lastIncrement = sheet.getRange(lastRow - 1, incrementCol).getValue(); 
    if (!lastIncrement) 
      lastIncrement = 0; 
      // Assign the new incremental number to the new row
      sheet.getRange(lastRow, incrementCol).setValue(lastIncrement + 1); 
      // Sort the sheet by the second column 
      sortSheetByColumn(sheet, 2); 
  }
  
function sortSheetByColumn(sheet, column) {
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.sort({column: column, ascending: true}); 
}

function createTrigger() {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "onFormSubmit") {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]); 
    }
  } 
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create(); 
}


Would you please edit the question to include sample data, and examples of the expected outcome.

The question asks “How can I achieve this using Google Apps Script?”. Would you please describe your expectations of an answer and include any work that you’ve done to answer the question yourself. Are you expecting a user to provide an entire script (noting that StackOverflow is not a free coding service) or, say, suggestions about how you might approach a specific problem that you can built into your own script.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The code I've come up with is a bit long so I will post in two parts

function onFormSubmit(e) {
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var incrementCol = sheet.getLastColumn() + 1;// Add a header for the incremental number column if not already present
if (lastRow == 1 && !sheet.getRange(1, incrementCol).getValue()) {
sheet.getRange(1, incrementCol).setValue("Incremental Number");}// Get the last incremental number var lastIncrement = sheet.getRange(lastRow - 1, incrementCol).getValue();
if (!lastIncrement) lastIncrement = 0;
// Assign the new incremental number to the new row

sheet.getRange(lastRow, incrementCol).setValue(lastIncrement + 1);
// Sort the sheet by the second column
sortSheetByColumn(sheet, 2);
}function sortSheetByColumn(sheet, column) {var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());range.sort({column: column, ascending: true});
}function createTrigger() {
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "onFormSubmit") {
ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
}

}
ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
.forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
.onFormSubmit()
.create();
}

Great, thanks. Don’t forget the sample data and example of the expected outcome.

I’ve got a script ready for you; will post asap. FWIW, the “trick” is to “unsort” before adding the increment number. BUT have you considered replacing all this with a simple query based on the response sheet and use the timestamp in place of the incremental number?

You want to create a script that will create an incrementing number as each submission is received.
The OPs script was almost correct. Consider the differences in the following answer:

Event Objects are used to identify

e.range.rowStart - the editted row
e.range.columnEnd - the last column of data


The rows must be "unsorted" before applying the incremental number. This ensures that the 2nd last row contains the highest increment number.
if (editedRow == 2 && !sheet.getRange(1, incrementCol).getValue()) { is modified:

if true - set the last increment to zero
if false, set the last increment to the previous value plus 1




function onFormSubmit(e) {

  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) DEBUG: Event Objects

  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  
  // get the Event variables
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart

  // get variables
  var incrementCol = e.range.columnEnd+1
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the edited row = "+editedRow+", and the incremental Column = "+incrementCol+", and the incremental value = "+sheet.getRange(1, incrementCol).getValue())

  // unsort the columns
  // Sort by Column A (Timestamp)
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, editedRow - 1, incrementCol);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Unsort data range = "+range.getA1Notation())
  range.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});

  // Add a header for the incremental number column if not already present 
  // and assign default increment starter
  if (editedRow == 2 && !sheet.getRange(1, incrementCol).getValue()) {
    sheet.getRange(1, incrementCol).setValue("Incremental Number");
    lastIncrement = 0; 
  }
  else{
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: Header exists, keep processing")
    // Get the last incremental number 
    var lastIncrement = sheet.getRange(editedRow - 1, incrementCol).getValue(); 
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the last increment = "+lastIncrement)
  }

  // Assign the new incremental number to the new row
  sheet.getRange(editedRow, incrementCol).setValue(lastIncrement + 1); 
  
  // Sort the sheet by the second column 
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,editedRow-1, incrementCol);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Sort range = "+range.getA1Notation())
  range.sort({column: 2, ascending: true}); 
}


A non-script alternative
=query({'Form Responses 1'!A1:C},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 is not null order by Col3, Col2, Col1 ")
